# Search text in GitHub

Tags: github, search, text

I'm pretty new to GitHub.
I want to find instances of the word "administrator" in two different filenames across all repositories in my organization. Is there way to do this in GitHub? 
I've tried **org:[MyOrg] administrator filename:[Filename1] filename: [Filename2]**, but the search didn't catch all instances of the word. Any ideas or additional tools I might need?

Answer (score 0):

General advice: this sounds like a job for GitHub advanced search: https://github.com/search/advanced.

I'm not sure how to create this search in one step, but a URL like the following should find what you're looking for.

https://github.com/search?l=&q=javascript+user%3Agatsbyjs+filename%3AREADME.md&type=Code

Replace "javascript" with your search term, "gatsbyjs" with your organization, and "README.md" with the filename you're interested in.

Comment: Thanks Jake! I tried advanced search, but the furthest I could get was to find all files that contain the word, but not every instance.